# Plotting a probability density based on the ratio of two random variables in PyMC3

Tags: rejection-sampling, probabilistic-programming

I am trying to graphically represent the ratio of two probability distributions:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp{(\frac{(-x)^2}{2})}$$
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{2} \exp{(-|x|)}$$

I'm a bit confused about how to call this in PyMC3, as I'm very new to it, but this is what I'm attempting:

```
with pm.Model() as m:
    fx = pm.Normal("fx", mu=0, sd=1)
    gx = pm.Laplace("gx", mu=0, b=1)
    ratio = fx/gx
n=100000
samp = ratio.sample(size = n)
```

I haven't had much luck with the PyMC documentation. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: *to graphically represent the ratio*, why don't u just plot the ratio instead of dealing with pymc?

Comment: Yes, this works functionally, but I was hoping to learn how to represent it with PyMC.